# Distribute and Pip for use with Python 3.2

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, pip, python-3.2, distribute

When installing modules with pip or distributes easy_install for python3, modules will instead install for python 2.7 or earlier. Im fairly new to both the mac operating system and python itself (4 months or so). I'd like to get distribute and pip installed and working for python 3.2.

When using easy_install or pip, things will work normally with installing for python 2.7. This is not what I wanted however and I tried to fix this by installing both pip and easy install with:

sudo curl https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py | **python3**

as opposed to

sudo curl https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py | **python**

This should accomplish what i wanted to do, however, after installing like that I get:

new-host-6:~ Eric$ pip install spynner

-bash: pip: command not found

If anyone has any experience with the above stated in getting pip and distributes easy_install to work for python3, help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you try doing `curl -O  https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py` and then `sudo python3 get-pip.py`? This is different from what you did.